# Meteor 0.9.1: ReferenceError: SimpleSchema is not defined

Tags: meteor

After deciding to create a new project and start fresh and then checkout the code for a separate project (that was in a working state) I'm getting the following error with simple-schema.  This schema was working so its likely that an update has broken it in some respect.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to sort this?

Terminal output:

```
$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/puzzle ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
W20140906-10:30:37.252(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20140906-10:30:37.339(-7)? (STDERR) /home/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.27.11fuo6h++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140906-10:30:37.339(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140906-10:30:37.340(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140906-10:30:37.340(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: SimpleSchema is not defined
W20140906-10:30:37.341(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/schema-Account-Type.js:5:26
W20140906-10:30:37.341(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/lib/schema-Account-Type.js:25:3
W20140906-10:30:37.341(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/me/puzzle/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:161:10
W20140906-10:30:37.342(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140906-10:30:37.342(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/graeme/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.27.11fuo6h++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140906-10:30:37.342(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/me/puzzle/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Schema:

```
AccountType = new Meteor.Collection("AccountType");

Schema = {};

Schema.AccountType = new SimpleSchema({

    accountType: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['test', 'live']

    },

    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function(){ return this.userId }
    }

});


SimpleSchema.debug = true;
AccountType.attachSchema(Schema.AccountType);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Resolved by the following steps - installing SimpleSchema:

- Try installing / reinstalling: aldeed:simple-schema.
- Looking at how to install packages: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html
- So, I found https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema on Atmosphere to get the correct install script:

  ```
  meteor add aldeed:simple-schema
  ```

  ([Reference](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema))

Comment: Adding these packages to the Meteor app also helps:

"
# Added for this project ...
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
erasaur:meteor-lodash
stolinski:stylus-multi
fortawesome:fontawesome
spiderable
fastclick
raix:handlebar-helpers
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:autoform
accounts-ui
accounts-password
matb33:bootstrap-glyphicons
msavin:jetsetter
zimme:active-route
gwendall:auth-client-callbacks
aldeed:simple-schema
"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, ended up having to create a new Meteor app though.
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/issues/147